# storyboard elements are not visible when using manual push navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i am using manual navigation on button click from one viewcontroller to another

```
nextpage *np =  [[nextpage alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushviewController:np animated:YES];
```

I included nextpage class on the viewcontroller in storyboard. But in this case the elements added via drag and drop are not visible while if i add manual elements via code they are visible from nextpage on navigating. Please help !

and If I add navigation from a button through a storyboard, in that case both coded elements and storyboard elements are visible. !

Comment: It's good practise to use `Nextpage` rather than `nextpage`.

Comment: I have already done that in my machine ...thnx anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
Pass a identifier to your view controller in storyboard.

```
nextpage *np = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"your identifier"];
[self.navigationController pushviewController:np animated:YES];
```

Comment: i tried this...in this case it is throwing an exception

Comment: actually my storyboard is showing it as next page instead of nextpage...any idea how to change it??

Comment: have you given a storyboard ID to ViewController.

Comment: error = this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key label.

Comment: u have a label in view controller which is not connected to an IBOutlet i think so.

Comment: perfect man ! thanks alot !! need one more help....when i click BACK on navigation bar...homepage navigation bar becomes unhidden ! any idea ?

Comment: was that navigation bar not there before.

Comment: no initialy its hidden i.e self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden =YES;

Comment: put the above code in -(void)viewWillAppear and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Content you've added in the storyboard will only appear if you load that view controller *from the storyboard*. By simply alloc/initing a new view controller you're losing all of the information you've added in the storyboard.

You can create a segue from a view controller to another one (i.e. not from a specific button) if you want to manually push, just use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, or you can add an identifier to the view controller and use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` to create your VC from the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

first of all give storyboard id to viewcontroller then add following code 
`Nextpage *nextPage = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NextpageIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushviewController:nextPage animated:YES];`